# Schedule urbanairship push notification

Tags: php, urbanairship.com

After reading documentation I have tried to write the following source:

```
$contents = array();
 //$contents['badge'] = "+1";
 $contents['alert'] = "Touchdown!";
 //$contents['sound'] = "cat.caf";
 $notification = array();
 $notification= $contents;

 $audience['tag'] = "49ers";

 $scheduled['scheduled_time'] = "2013-04-01T18:45:30";

 $push['push'] = array("audience"=> $audience, "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>"all");
 $response = array();
 array_push($response, array("name" => "My schedule", "schedule"=> $scheduled));
 array_push($response, $push);


 $json = json_encode($response);
 //echo "Payload: " . $json . "\n"; //show the payload

 $session = curl_init(PUSHURL);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, APPKEY . ':' . PUSHSECRET);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, True);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, False);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;'));
 $content = curl_exec($session);
// echo "Response: " . $content . "\n";
print_r($content);
 // Check if any error occured
 $response = curl_getinfo($session);
 if($response['http_code'] != 202) {  
 $error = "Got negative response from server: " . $response['http_code'] . "\n";
 } else {

     $success = "Message has been sent successfully";
 }
```

I am getting error = 0.
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: You're scheduling the message for 2013.... I'm assuming the scheduled message needs to be scheduled for the future.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Tried to put 2016 but still not working. Getting 0 in response code.

Comment: Are you able to get normal push notifications to work through Urban Airship?

Comment: Yes normal push is working fine.

Comment: What is the URL you are pointing to? EG, it should be https://go.urbanairship.com/api/schedules/ ​

Your payload should be as such:
{"name" : "scheduled push name", "schedule" : {"scheduled_time" : "2015-10-18T15:30:00"},"push" : {"audience" : "all", "notification" : {"alert" : "This will be sent at 3:30 PM UTC"}, "device_types" : "all"}}

Comment: Yes I am using 'go.urbanairship.com/api/schedules' and can you please check my payload is that correct or something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem with the help of @dperconti (thank you very much).

I am posting a solution to 'how to schedule push for urbanairship' so others may find it helpful.

Code is:

```
 define('APPKEY','xxxx'); // Your App Key
 define('PUSHSECRET', 'xxxx'); // Your Master Secret
 define('PUSHURL', 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/schedules/');

 $contents = array();
 //$contents['badge'] = "+1";
 $contents['alert'] = "Touchdown!";
 //$contents['sound'] = "cat.caf";
 $notification = array();
 $notification= $contents;

 $audience = "all";

 $scheduled['scheduled_time'] = "2016-04-01T18:45:30";

//   $push['push'] = array("audience"=> $audience, "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>"all");
 $response = array();
 array_push($response, array("name" => "My schedule", "schedule"=> $scheduled, "push" => array("audience"=> $audience, "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>"all")));
//   array_push($response, $push);


 $json = json_encode($response);
 echo "Payload: " . $json . "<br><br><br>"; //show the payload

 $session = curl_init(PUSHURL);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, APPKEY . ':' . PUSHSECRET);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, True);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, False);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;'));
 $content = curl_exec($session);
// echo "Response: " . $content . "\n";
print_r($content);
 // Check if any error occured
 $response = curl_getinfo($session);
 if($response['http_code'] != 202) {
     $error = "Got negative response from server: " . $response['http_code'] . "\n";
 } else {

     $success = "Message has been sent successfully";
 }

 curl_close($session);
```